# How to avoid duplicate enum value from other .cxx

Tags: c++, enums

I have a large number of files in my code base. I am trying to compile my code base using other library that has one file a.h.
I am running into compilation problem if I include say a.h file in my code base that has already defined some of the values with same enum as defined in a.h. For example:

in "a.h" header file

```
typedef enum mylist_s
{
   FIRST,
   SECOND,
   THIRD,
   FOUR,
   ::::::
} mylist_e;
```

in other .cxx file as shown below (if it has definition same as defined in mylist)

```
static const char FIRST = 1;
```

I understand there is a definition of same variable again. 
I don't want to change my code base with new variable.
Also since a.h is include in both .c and .cxx file I can not use namespace to encapsulate it with other name.

I also don't want to change name in a.h file. 
Is there an any other way I can handle this situation without changing enum value name.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's what `namespace`s were invented for. You *can* wrap the `FIRST = 1` in one.

Comment: put all of **your code** in a namespace

Comment: I can't use namespace as "a.h" file is included in .c files as well. May be we need to look for equivalent of namespace in .c

Comment: You don't follow. You use a nemspace in your `cxx` files, not the header which you can't change.

Comment: BTW, you also have an option of placing `#include` directives inside a namespace..

Comment: Are you able to change to `enum class` instead for these enums that can overlap with some variables?

Answer (score 1):

C++ [`namepsace`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/namespace-in-c/)'s are to prevent name collisions from occurring.

Defining all of your implementation code inside of a custom namespace should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I used for the same problem as mentioned below:

```
struct mylist_s
{
    enum Type
    {
        FIRST,
        SECOND,
        THIRD,
        FOUR
    };
};
typedef mylist_s::Type mylist_e;
```